# Disable the Shadow Animation in Shell TabBar

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbar, custom-renderer, app-shell

If I switch between my different tabs, I allways get this little click animation that looks like a shadow or sth.
I use a custom Renderer for my Shell, but how can I disable this animation?

[Here is a picture of the click animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NHdu.png)

Comment: Check your tags' descriptions -- the "shell" tag here is for _text-based interactive command interpreters_. As far as I can tell it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: ...as for the question, a [mre] showing the shortest possible code that reproduces the undesired behavior would be a good place to start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. Here is my code:

```
        public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
        {
            
        }
        public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
        {
            Android.Graphics.Color elevationBGColor = ((Color)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["ElevationBGColor"]).ToAndroid();


            bottomView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityUnlabeled;
            bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(elevationBGColor);
            int[][] Tintstates = new int[][]
            {
                new int[] {-Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked}, // unchecked
                new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked}  // pressed
            };

            int[] Tintcolors = new int[]
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.Color.White.ToAndroid(),
                ((Color)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["PrimaryColor"]).ToAndroid()
            };

            ColorStateList TintList = new ColorStateList(Tintstates, Tintcolors)

            bottomView.ItemIconTintList = TintList;
            bottomView.ItemRippleColor = null;
        }
```

In this code I also set a color change to the item i selected in my navbar, but the code i was searching for was

```
bottomView.ItemRippleColor = null;
```